# contenteditable, cannot edit a blank span

Tags: java, jquery, html

I am using contenteditable attribute in this way. 
${row.pno}.

As the data is retrieved from the DB, few values can be null. I can edit the span with some value. The problem is I cannot edit the blank(null text) span. How can i achieve this.

Thanks and Regards
Adeeb

Comment: Showing part of your code will make it easier to help you!

Comment: just return a blank character instead and it should allow you to edit, `<span contenteditable>&nbsp;</span>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An element with the `contenteditable` attribute is editable even if the element is initially empty, as in `<span contenteditable></span>`. The user just can’t focus on it by clicking on it. But he can use the TAB key to move to the element and then type or paste something.

The conclusions depend on the context. For example, if the `span` element is the sole content of a table cell, you could set `display: block` on it, making it occupy the entire. Assuming that other cells imply nonzero width and height for that cell, the editable element would have them too and be clickable.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. When i select that blank td and hit tab, i am able to edit. I have given the onclick events, which do not work, until i write something and then click on it. Otherwise if text exists, the onclick has no problem.